# How to submit the form after calling preventDefault() on submit button ASP.NET I tried to call submit function on my form but nothing I am stucked?

Tags: asp.net

This is my form and I want to call Create ActionResut if i don't find any object with JSON result method:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "InspekcijskeKontrole", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "forma1"}))
```

{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Inspekcijska kontrola</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspekcijskoTijeloId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("InspekcijskoTijeloId", null,"Odaberite inspekcijsko tijelo.....", new { @class = "form-control", @id="kombo3" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspekcijskoTijeloId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProizvodId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("ProizvodId", null,"Odaberite proizvod.....", new { @class = "form-control", @id="kombo4" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProizvodId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DatumInspekcijskeKontrole, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DatumInspekcijskeKontrole, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DatumInspekcijskeKontrole, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rezultat, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rezultat, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rezultat, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProizvodSiguran, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProizvodSiguran)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProizvodSiguran, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Unesi" class="btn btn-success"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the method which I want to execute before submmiting the form I prevent submmiting with e.preventDefault() this method checks if something exist into database but how to go back on sumbit, how to cancel this e.preventDefault() if value doesn't exist to execute submit event not on click?

```
$("#btnSave").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var zahtjev = $.getJSON("/InspekcijskeKontrole/Check?id1=" + $("#kombo3").val() + "&id2=" + $("#kombo4").val());

    zahtjev.done(function (data) {

        if (data.InspekcijskoTijeloId != -1 && data.ProizvodId != -1) {
            $.getJSON("/Proizvodi/VratiIme/" + data.ProizvodId, function (ime) {

                if (ime != null) {
                    $("#modalni1 p").text("Inspekcijska kontrola za " + ime + " je vec izvrsena");
                    $("#modalni1").modal({ backdrop: "static" });
                }
            });

        }
    });
    zahtjev.fail(function (greska) {
        $("#sp1").text(greska.responseText);
    });

});
```

Comment: Call `.submit()` on the `form` element?

Comment: No it doesn't work I tried thx anyway

Comment: I do not see any ***ASP.Net*** in your code - not even button server control.

Comment: I am doing ASP.NET MVC Application ?

Comment: when you try .submit(), what error are you getting in console?

Comment: I got Uncaught TypeError:undefined is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Are you wiring this up inside a jQuery document ready function? Something like

```
$(function() {
   $("#btnSave").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     ...
});
```

I wonder if your click handler is not firing because the JavaScript to wire up the click event runs before the element actually exists. jQuery will run without error in this case, but the event will not fire and you'll get the default behaviour.

Comment: My click event is fired but I want to go back on submit if my $.getJson doesn't return object I tried with $("#form").submit();

Comment: I tried like this `if(zahtjev!=null){ e.preventDefault()}else{$("#form").submit()};`

Answer (score 0):

You can change you `input` type to `button`

```
<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Unesi" class="btn btn-success"/>
```

Then submit your `form` manually using `.submit()` with you form id

Something like:

```
$("#btnSave").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var zahtjev = $.getJSON("/InspekcijskeKontrole/Check?id1=" + $("#kombo3").val() + "&id2=" + $("#kombo4").val());

    zahtjev.done(function (data) {

        if (data.InspekcijskoTijeloId != -1 && data.ProizvodId != -1) {
            $.getJSON("/Proizvodi/VratiIme/" + data.ProizvodId, function (ime) {

                if (ime != null) {
                    $("#modalni1 p").text("Inspekcijska kontrola za " + ime + " je vec izvrsena");
                    $("#modalni1").modal({ backdrop: "static" });
                }
            });

        }

        $(#yourFormidHere).submit(); //if you want to submit here for example

    });
    zahtjev.fail(function (greska) {
        $("#sp1").text(greska.responseText);
    });

});
```

Hope this will help. Let me know in case of any problem. Thank you